# Запуск процесса из потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно запустить процесс не блокируя основной поток, но и получить уведомление о завершении запущенного процесса?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Необходимости в отдельном потоке нет.

Примерно так:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "myprocess.exe";
//подписываемся на событие завершения процесса и включаем уведомления
process.Exited += process_Exited;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//асинхронная операция, не блокирует поток, из которого была вызвана
process.Start();
```

Где `process_Exited` — это ваш обработчик завершения процесса.

Если по каким-то причинам завершения процесса нужно дождаться синхронно, то после `Start()` нужно вызвать метод `WaitForExit()`.

Comment: А чего сразу минусовать? Если на обработку завершения потока будет долгий код, то основной поток этим заблокируется. В отдельной триде этот Ваш код этого вызывать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Вынести запуск процесса и ожидания его завершения в отдельный тред?